# I can't find Library/MobileDevice to place my provisioning file

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning

I Cannot find the Directory "MobileDevice" in "Library" or "myuser/Library" and I need to find it to put my "Distribution Provisioning Profile" that I made on it.

I already use XCode 4.1

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 2):

You should just drag the profile into Xcode....

Comment: thx, but How can I do?

I see only one way to doing this: from finder or terminal !!!

Comment: Do I have to add it to the project? otherwise, I just have to drag&drop it on Xcode, but where exactly? (I'm in the last version, and she's very different)

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just drag the profile onto the Xcode icon. Then  in Xcode, go into the 'Organizer' - you should be able to see the installed profile. Then you just need to make sure your project is set to be signed with that profile...

Comment: After hours of fiddling around, simply dragging the provisioning profile into Xcode fixed it. Thanks!